# Terminal field positioning through Telnet

Tags: c#, .net, terminal, telnet

I'm working on a project which connects to a device through telnet. Once logged into the device, it automatically displays an interactive terminal menu. Using putty, everything displays in particular locations via field codes (in the format of `\x1b[<row>;<column>f`). Navigating the menu works fine just sending the appropriate input for the menu item.

```
    Main Menu
------------------
A) Statistics
B) Configuration
```

Sending A transitions to the Statistics page. B to Configuration. On the Configuration page there are options to change values.

```
Configuration Menu
------------------
A) Line Length     80
B) Line Style      Normal
```

And the new values are done in-place on the page. Again, with putty, this all happens as expected. The cursor is positioned in the correct location in order to enter the new values. Using the chosen telnet library (Thought.Net.Telnet) doesn't appear to allow this same functionality. Up until now, it wasn't necessary. With the new device the stream for the page comes out as a bunch of field codes with the text following.

Is there a way to target specific fields for modification? Is there a part of the telnet and/or terminal protocol I can use to simulate the input as through a terminal emulator? Just sending the field code location for the matching field? I haven't yet tested it as I discovered the problem literally just before I had to head out the door for an appointment. I'm asking before I head back in the morning to get a jump start on this problem.

Comment: I find it kinda disturbing that there's a terminal emulator out there that doesn't appear to support VT-100 standard terminal codes.

Comment: Well, the Telnet component isn't a terminal emulator.